# Custom URL for cake php

Tags: cakephp

I am using `cake php version 1.3.11` and using 2 tables one is `article_category` and second one is `articles`.
On article category  storing article category name and articles table using for articles details with article category id.

I create a article controller to list category wise article list. Now that url display is like this
 `mysite/articles/index/<article_category_id>`
Instead of that type listing I would like to display url like this
 `mysite/<article_category_name>/index`
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, couple of things there.

**Conventions** *[follow Cookbook for more and better understanding](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html)*

1. Your `article_category` should have been just `categories`.
2. `article_category` type of names are used for join tables (many-to-many relationships) for HABTM type relations. Even as a join table, it should have been `articles_categories`. You can use `Inflectore::pluralize('singularname')` to create plural cases.*[follow Cookbook for more](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#associations-linking-models-together)*

CakePHP has a [Router Class](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html), that handles connecting custom routes. It is located in `App/Config/route.php`. You can use it to meet almost any URL demands.

Now for the solution,

- Modify your `categories` (article_category in your case) table to contain a field called `slug`. I would recommend having slug as compared to name.
- Define a new route *[follow CookBook for more](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#passing-parameters-to-action)*

  ```
  // In app/Config/routes.php 
  Router::connect(
      '/articles/index/:id-:slug', // E.g. /articles/index/3-technology
      array('controller' => 'articles', 'action' => 'index'),
      array(
      // order matters since this will simply map ":id" to $articleId in your action
          'pass' => array('id', 'slug'),
          'id' => '[0-9]+'
     )
  );
  ```
- modify your controller action to accept slug

  ```
  public function index( $id, $slug = null ) {

  }
  ```